# Circ above $D^3$ in a nice way

Tags: superscripts

I want to denote the interior of `$D^3$`, so I use `$\overset{\circ}{D^3}$`. This looks like this:

[image]

However I find this kind of ugly, and would rather have the circ just above the `$D$`, but then `$\overset{\circ}{D}^3$` is giving even stranger things, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to have what I want? This would be basically the `\circ` as in the second image, and the `3` as in the first.

Comment: How do you display basic math on this site? Not with dollars?

Comment: to display output, you need to insert a visual.  (see [how can i upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/579))  this site doesn't use mathjax, since the whole purpose of this site is to handle questions about the code, which would be obscured by displaying only the output.

Comment: `\mathring{D}^3`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `\mathring{...}`, rather than `\overset{\circ}{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathring{D^{3}}
\qquad
\mathring{D}^{3}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `amsmath` package is not really necessary for this, but it's recommended for any math document.

[image]